# Index of $(K^*)^m$ inside $K^*$ for $K$ a local field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $m\geq 1$ and $K$ be a local field containing the $m$-roots of $1$ (I am unsure to what extent this hypothesis is relevant), and denote by $v$ a normalized valuation of $K$ given by a uniformizer $\pi$. Denote by $\mathfrak o$ its ring of integers, and $k$ the residue field. The claim I would like to show is the following

> The subgroup $(K^*)^m$ of $K^*$ has index $\frac{m^2}{|m|_v}$ where $|m|_v$ is the normed absolute value of $m$ at $v$.

I have difficulties writing down a proof of this statement. Moreover, I feel like my work is contradicting the result in some case. Here is what I have done so far.

A general element $x$ of $K^*$ can be uniquely written as $x=u\pi^{v(x)}$ with $u$ a unit. Because we are interested in computing the index of $(K^*)^m$, we may assume  that $v(x)=0,\ldots,m-1$. To understand the structure of the quotient, we need to study how the unit $u$ reduces inside, that is what can we say of $\mathfrak o^*/(\mathfrak o^*)^m$.

In the case where $m$ is a unit in $K$, writing down $p$ the characteristic of $k$ and $q=p^f$ its order, we have $(p,m)=(q,m)=1$. Then every non-zero element of $k$ is an $m$-th power (this can be seen using the fact that $k^*$ is cyclic). Because the polynomial $X^m-u$ is separable in $k[X]$ for any unit $u$, Hensel's lemma then implies that it has a root in $\mathfrak o$, that is in fact $\mathfrak o^* = (\mathfrak o^*)^m$. Thus, the quotient $K^*/(K^*)^m$ is generated by the image of $\pi$ and has order $m$ in this case (even though $|m|_v = 1$ since $m$ is a unit, so this seems to contradict the above statement, unless I am very confused... ?)

In the case where $m$ is not a unit, I fail to see how to proceed. Maybe we can write $m=p^am'$ with $m'$ prime to $p$ and reduce to the case where $m$ is a power of $p$.

Would somebody be able to give me a hand with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic step in your argument is when you conclude from $(p,m)=1$ that every element of $k$ is an $m$-th power, which is not true. As an example, consider $K={\mathbb Q}_p$, $k={\mathbb F}_p$ and $m = p-1$, in which case $(p,m)=1$ but $x^m=1$ for all $x\in k$. The point is that $k^\times$ is cyclic of order $q-1$, not $q$.

Your use of Hensel's Lemma for $(p,m)=1$ is correct, though, and shows $({\mathscr O}^{\times}:({\mathscr O}^{\times})^m)=(k^\times:(k^{\times})^m)=|\mu_m(k)|$, so $(K^\times:(K^{\times})^m)=m |\mu_m(k)|$ for $(p,m)=1$ (which is the same as $m^2 / \|m\|_K$ because you assumed $|\mu_m(k)|=m$ and because $\|m\|_K=1$).

Comment: Ah, of course ! I'm pretty ashamed of my mistake here, confusing the role of $q$ and $q-1$... Indeed, what I had in mind all falls apart (for the better !). So now this case is clear thanks to your help, I am very grateful. Would you have a hint in the case $m$ is not a unit (ie $m$ is divisible by $p$) ? In this situation, Hensel's lemma wouldn't apply anymore.

Comment: For any $m$ (no hypothesis on $\mu_m$ nor the residual characteristic is needed), you can find an indication of a quick proof in Serre's "Local Fields", chap.14, ex.3, which uses the so called Herbrand quotient (a very useful technical trick).

Comment: @Suzet Apologies for my late reply - I'm tied into work and haven't found the time to extend my comment. The proof I am aware of is from Neukirch's Class Field Theory book (available online) and it also uses Herbrant quotients, as Nguyen also suggested. It would be interesting, though, to see if one unraveling definitions yields a short, self-contained proof of the statement. But again, I'm lacking the time to attempt that at the moment.